# Set variable value inside switch statement Tcl

Tags: switch-statement, tcl

Attempting to set two variables values according to the user input in a third variable. I am trying to use a switch statement but I am not sure if it is actually possible.

```
switch $sample_type_input {
  CORE { set sample_type 1 \
       set cutting ""}
  SWC  { set sample_type 2 \
       set cutting ""}
  CUTT { set sample_type 3 \
       set cutting "CUTT" }
}
```

I keep getting a 'wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newBalue?"` error.

Comment: Take out the backslashes and you will be all right.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow I get the same error.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow is right, thats all you need. The executed block (between the braces after the switch case) is just like any block of tcl, so a new line will separate the statements. The semi-colon can be used to terminate a statement if you want another on the same line. Having the slash tells it to ignore the new line and so your two `set? s merge into one and you end up with too many arguments.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow Did you want to make your comment an answer I will mark it as the answer that worked?

Comment: Sure. I've posted an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash at the end of the line acts as a line continuation, concatenating this line and the next line into a single logical line of code. This is necessary in a case where one has to break up a command invocation into two or more lines, because of the parsing rules:

```
set foo
    bar
```

is interpreted as two command invocations: `set foo` and `bar`.

```
set foo \
    bar
```

is a single command invocation: `set foo bar`.

Note that the backslash must be the very last character before the newline: e.g. a space between the backslash and the newline simply makes the invocation end with a regular space and a quoted space:

```
# there is a space after the backslash here
set foo \ 
puts "{$foo}"
# => { }
```

If your command invocation includes an argument in braces, it's typically quite all right to break it up into several lines without a backslash, since all whitespace including newlines is quoted by the braces anyway:

```
set foo {
    bar
    baz
}
```

And indeed if the argument within braces is a script containing more than one command invocation, you need to break it up into lines (or insert semicolons), since newlines are significant as command line separators. Therefore this fails:

```
if {true} {set foo bar \
    set baz quz}
```

as it concatenates two command invocations into the single code line `set foo bar set baz quz`, providing the `set` command with five arguments when it expects one or two. The correct way is to write it as

```
if {true} {set foo bar ; set baz quz}
```

or

```
if {true} {set foo bar
    set baz quz}
```

letting the semicolon or newline separate the command invocations in the script argument. Stylistic convention is to add additional newlines at the beginning and end of a multi-line script argument, like this:

```
if {true} {
    set foo bar
    set baz quz
}
```

This is similar to C brace styles, but not quite the same thing. One common beginner mistake is to try to use some other C bracing convention such as

```
if {true}
{
    set foo bar
    set baz quz
}
```

which won't work since it introduces a codeline-separating newline between the first and second arguments to `if`. If you can't live without this bracing convention, you need to add a line continuation:

```
if {true} \
{
    set foo bar
    set baz quz
}
```

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found somewhere else in my script. @Hoodiecrow was correct about the `\`, they needed to be removed but unfortunately for me I was getting the same error from the other part of my code.

Comment: Hi @Lanzafame, just wanted to check you know that you can look in the `errorInfo` variable to get a sort of stack trace after an error.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. But for this situation it doesn't work because I am using Tcl through another program (Paradigm Geolog 7.1) and the error was coming from a line that used the API. All I get from Geolog is a static feedback window.

Comment: Shame! It might be possible for you to call your tcl wrapped in a catch, to show you the info if you have an error: `if {[catch {//your code here//} ]} {puts $errorInfo}` - might help future debugging. Good luck!

Comment: Looking at the stack traces is _very_ helpful. Tcl usually manages to be pretty exact about where the problem is (and always about where it _thinks_ the error is) but the error line is currently relative to the procedure and not the file…

Comment: @DonalFellows as I already mentioned to Captain because I am running the script in a programs environment I don't have full access to the output. I am yet to try Captains suggestion but I don't have high hopes... geology software is rather clunky most of the time when it comes to stuff other geology.